# Evaluate orientationEvent and setting a value?

Tags: jquery, orientation, screen-orientation, device-orientation

If I have an onChange function firing when an orientation change has happened, how do I set a value within the onChange that will update a jquery selector.  For instance:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){    
    var onChanged = function() {
            if(window.orientation == 90 || window.orientation == -90){
                image = '<img src="images/land_100.png">';
            }else{
                image = '<img src="images/port_100.png">';
            }
     }
        $(window).bind(orientationEvent, onChanged).bind('load', onChanged);
        $('#bgImage').html(image); //won't update image
   });
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to put the update to the image inside the onChanged function so that every time the orientation changes, the image HTML will be changed.

```
$(document).ready(function(){   

   // The event for orientation change
   var onChanged = function() {

      // The orientation
      var orientation = window.orientation,

      // If landscape, then use "land" otherwise use "port"
      image = orientation == 90 || orientation == -90 ? "land" : "port";

      // Insert the image
      $('#bgImage').html('<img src="images/'+image+'_100.png">');

   };

   // Bind the orientation change event and bind onLoad
   $(window).bind(orientationEvent, onChanged).bind('load', onChanged);

});
```